# How to Convert char* to LPWSTR in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How to Convert char* to LPWSTR in VC++ ?

```
LPNETRESOURCEW nr = NULL;
memset(&nr, 0, sizeof (NETRESOURCE));
nr->lpLocalName = strDriveLetter.GetBuffer(strDriveLetter.GetLength()); // this line giving me error "Cannot Convert char* to LPWSTR"
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function;

```
const char* msg = "foobarbaz";
int len = strlen(msg) + 1;
wchar_t *w_msg = new wchar_t[len];
memset(w_msg, 0, len);
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, NULL, msg, -1, w_msg, len);
```

Comment: question is there a quideline about where to put the * in c/c++ code? you do something different on the first line and the third line of code. If not follow a guideline is there a reason you do it this way?

Comment: Hi @BuddyJoe. Not sure if there is a specific guideline, but I can tell you that if you declare multiple variables on the same line, ala `int* c, p;`
You're going to have problems if you expect that both `c` and `p` are pointers. 
Unfortunately, you'd want to write something like `int *c, *p;`. Having said that, I don't like declaring multiple variables on the same line.

Answer (score -1):

`memset(&nr, 0, sizeof (NETRESOURCE));` here nr is a NULL pointer. This is not correct. You should have nr point to a valid memory first by either using explicit allocation like `new` or on allocate on stack.

Comment: *This is not correct.* **This is correct**. `&nr` is not a `nullptr`. There is another issue: `sizeof(nr) !=  sizeof(NETRESOURCE)`.