# Cannot convert CHAR to LPWSTR

Tags: c++, lpwstr

I encountered a compilation error in Visual Studio 2015, that I am trying to convert `char` data to `LPWSTR`. Can I? Or does it work only with string types?

Here is a piece of my code :

```
    ⋮
FILE *sortie;
char fichier[256];//   <--- HERE s my char table

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //on masque 
    HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);

    int i, lettre, result, lastresult, lastletter, compteur;

    GetCurrentDirectory(256, fichier); 
    strcat(fichier, "\\fichierlog.txt");
```

---

Before posting my question I was at:

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28C2664%29&rd=true
2. [C++ cannot convert from enum to LPCTSTR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058801/c-cannot-convert-from-enum-to-lpctstr)
3. [How to Convert char* to LPWSTR in VC++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561818/how-to-convert-char-to-lpwstr-in-vc)

I didn't find my case :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of your current code:

```
FILE *sortie;
char fichier[256];//   <--- HERE s my char table

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //on masque 
    HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);

    int i, lettre, result, lastresult, lastletter, compteur;

    GetCurrentDirectory(256, fichier); 
    strcat(fichier, "\\fichierlog.txt");
```

do e.g.

```
auto main() -> int
{
    //on masque 
    HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);

    int i, lettre, result, lastresult, lastletter, compteur;

    std::wstring fichier( MAX_PATH, L'\0' );//   <--- HERE s my char table
    const DWORD len = GetCurrentDirectory( fichier.size(), &fichier[0] );
    if( len == 0 || len >= fichier.size() ) { throw std::runtime_error( "GetCurrentDirectory failed." ); }
    fichier.resize( len );
    fichier += L"/fichierlog.txt";

    std::ifstream sortie( fichier );
```

This should fix three issues:

- You're compiling as Unicode (probably a Visual Studio project), but the code is for the Windows ANSI API.
- You're using a C++ compiler, but the code is low level C.
- Too small buffer for maximum path length, and possible buffer overrun for the concatenation.

Note that the `ifstream` constructor that accepts a wide string is a Microsoft extension. It will however be practically required for Windows C++ compilers by the file system addition to the standard library in C++17.

Comment: Your answer is better than mine here. I was wondering is it enough to initialize the string with zero as in `fichier(256, 0);` or does it have to be `L'\0'`?

Comment: it s clarifying my problem  !

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: `0` and `L'\0'` have the same effect here, it's just a zero value that's implicitly converted to `wchar_t`. The character literal is just for clarity. But I often use e.g. `L'#'` in order to more easily detect off-by-one errors, which could leave one or more `#` characters in the result. I have yet to detect one, running on 20 years or so with this scheme. But I ain't giving up! :)

Comment: Thanks. `std::wstring` has about 20 different constructors, I wasn't sure if I had the right one.

Answer (score 2):

You are compiling with unicode, so you have to use `wchar_t` to declare the strings. Instead of `strcat` use the unicode version which is `wcscat`.

Also change the strings "\fichierlog.txt" become **L**"\fichierlog.txt"

```
FILE *sortie;
//char fichier[256];//   <--- HERE s my char table
wchar_t fichier[256];//   <--- HERE s my char table

//on masque 
HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);

int i, lettre, result, lastresult, lastletter, compteur;

GetCurrentDirectory(256, fichier);
//strcat(fichier, "\\fichierlog.txt");
wcscat(fichier, L"\\fichierlog.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Visual Studio project is set to compile using "widechars" as default encoding (aka UNICODE), so all Windows APIs take `wchar_t` arrays instead of `char` arrays when handling strings.

Either set your project to use standard charset or specify the ASCII version of `GetCurrentDirectory` by using `GetCurrentDirectoryA` instead.

`GetCurrentDirectory` is actually not a function, but a pre-processor macro that will route you to `GetCurrentDirectoryA` or `GetCurrentDirectoryW` depending on what enconding your compiler is set to use.

Comment: That is my problem ,i c now.